# Stretch / shrink parent div to fit content's width

Tags: css, html, width, parent, children

I am trying trying to make a div's width as wide as it's content. Here's a fidle to show what I mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/djxpU/

I want the **blue area** to be as wide as the white. I tried `float:left` and `display:inline-block`, however they won't work with `position:absolute;`. Any workarounds?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make a div fill the remaining screen space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-remaining-screen-space)

Comment: Just an FYI, IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: Because you're using `position:absolute`, the elements with white bg are no longer in the flow, so the blue block actually doesn't contain anything.

Comment: I'm using a grid plugin (masonry), it's coded that way. I guess there's no solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

Block-level elements actually do this naturally. The problem you have is, absolute positioned elements are taken out of the normal flow, so the block can't wrap around your white boxes.

Is there a reason you need them positioned absolute?

EDIT: If you just wanted the white boxes to be centered, here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/Marconius/djxpU/1/

Code (because I have to): `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: Yes you are right, I just want the white boxes to be centered. The problem is that it's a grid. Which mean I need to wrap all the X's with the absolute positions.

Comment: Ah, then there's really not much you can do. Could you not just manually set the size of the containing divs?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the white area to fit the blue parent, you'd set the width of the white to 100% `#X{
width:100%;
}`

Comment: In this case that wouldn't happen, because of the positioning used

Comment: I want the opposite, the blue to fit the white )

Answer (score 0):

By default a div will be the width of its parent and will display as block.  Here is an example of the divs filling the available space while still maintaining the left margin.

Apply this to your 'X' divs: `{ margin-left: 120px; height: 40px; background-color: white;}`

http://jsfiddle.net/yz3Dk/

Comment: I'm not sure how I should have worded it instead, but that's not what I want.